# Entity Framework - Many to Many relationship not saving to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I have stumbled upon a problem with Entity Framework this morning.

I have following code mapping a modified entity and saving it into database.

```
    public Group Save(Group x)
    {
        using (var db = new HostContext())
        {
            db.Projects.Attach(x.Project);

            if (x.ID != 0)
            {
                db.AttachableObjects.Attach(x);
                var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
                manager.ChangeObjectState(x, EntityState.Modified);
            }
            else
            {
                db.AttachableObjects.Add(x);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

I call Save method with existing group as a parameter. Group contains one user I want to add as a member.

The method finishes successfully, however the relationship is not persisted in database. 
Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT: These are my classes

```
class User : AttachableObject
{

    ...

    private List<Group> memberof;

    [DataMember]
    [InverseProperty("Members")]
    public List<Group> MemberOf
    {
        get { return memberof; }
        set { memberof = value; }
    }

    ...
}

class Group : AttachableObject
{

    ...

    private List<User> members;

    [DataMember]
    [InverseProperty("MemberOf")]
    public List<User> Members
    {
        get { return members; }
        set { members = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

EDIT2: This is where the Save method is called

```
    public Group AcceptInvite(int id)
    {
        var mapper = new InviteMapper();
        var userMapper = new UserMapper();
        var groupMapper = new GroupMapper();

        var invite = mapper.Find(id);

        if (invite != null)
        {
            var group = groupMapper.Find(invite.GroupID);
            var user = userMapper.Find(invite.InviteeID);

            group.Members.Add(user);

            mapper.Delete(invite.ID);
            return groupMapper.Save(group);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

EDIT3: My mappers

```
public class GroupMapper
{
    public Group Find(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new HostContext())
        {
            return db.AttachableObjects
                .Include("Project")
                .OfType<Group>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the mappers is the same, only using their own tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the relationship info of `Project`, you are only setting `x` to modified, relationship info must be changed explicitly.

So `x.Project` must have some property that points back to `Group`, you need to set it so the change is recorded.

I am guessing that `x` is resurrected via some deserialization process?

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't describe my problem clearly. The relationship that's not mapping is M:N relationship between classes User and Group. I have edited my original post with the code of said classes. The property Members of Group contains the user I want to make a member (the x).

Comment: I understand.. when are you adding the user object to the group?  Does that happen and then the object is ser/deser?

Comment: The user and group objects are obtained from the database using ef, the user is then added to the group and the group is used as parametr in my Save method I posted in my question. The objects are not deserialized.

Comment: well then if the user is loaded into the group to begin with why are you expecting an Add to occur?  You need to show where you are adding the user to the group, if you are not adding then I have no idea what problem you are describing.

Comment: i noticed you have `[DataMember]` are you sending over the wire or is all this loaded locally?